# installed netatalk but still cant connect by afp

Tags: macosx

i have a new server install. I just installed netatalk and avahi. I see my server appear on my mac but when i connect it tells me there was a problem connecting to this server. I have

`AFPD_UAMLIST="-U uams_dhx2.so"`

set. I thought this was what was required for Lion. I hope someone can help.

Here is the error message in /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]: ===============================================================
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]: INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 2413 (2.2-beta4)
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]: ===============================================================
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]: BACKTRACE: 3 stack frames:
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]:  #0 /usr/sbin/afpd(netatalk_panic+0x1c) [0x7f18b5ce449c]
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]:  #1 /usr/sbin/afpd(+0x4d59c) [0x7f18b5ce459c]
Mar  2 17:48:23 superMassive afpd[2413]:  #2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x36420) [0x7f18b4cc0420]
```

Comment: Can you post the error message produce when there is a problem connecting to the server please.

Comment: I can see the afp drive in finder. When i click it and enter wrong credentials (on purpose) the windows shakes while if i enter the right credentials it accepts the response. However, after a while a window pops up that says: There was a problem connecting to the server “superMassive” in bold. Then under that it says Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator. Is there some way for me to get you better info from terminal perhaps?

Comment: I have added the error message in an edit to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to this at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netatalk/+bug/810732

There is a bug in netatalk.

You need to edit `/etc/netatalk/afpd.conf` and replace `uams_dhx2.so` with `uams_dhx2_passwd.so`. All is working now!!! woot!!!!